# Difference between top 2 over multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables

**tblStation**

```
StationId | TPTagId
1         |  7
2         |  8
3         |  9
```

**tblValues**

```
DateAndTime              | TPTagId | Val
2017-01-01 13:00:00.000  |   7     | 500
2017-01-01 13:15:00.000  |   7     | 700
2017-01-01 13:30:00.000  |   7     | 750  
2017-01-01 13:23:00.000  |   8     | 610
2017-01-01 13:24:00.000  |   8     | 630
2017-01-01 13:25:00.000  |   8     | 640
2017-01-01 13:49:00.000  |   9     | 888
2017-01-01 13:49:30.000  |   9     | 890
2017-01-01 13:49:45.000  |   9     | 901
```

The TagId in tblStation shows where it's value is stored in the tblValues.

I want to find the difference between the top 2 values when ordered by date descending for each station.

So in the above example my result set would be:

**Results**

```
StationId |  Difference
1         |  50
2         |  10
3         |  11
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

There is no primary key on the Values table so I think this means I can't do a self join?

I have this so far, which gets me all the stations and their values grouped by StationId and the DateAndTime descending. But I don't know how to get the difference between the top 2 of each group

```
select s.StationID, v.DateAndTime, v.Val
from dbo.tblValues v
inner join dbo.tblStation s on s.TPTagId = v.TPTagId
group by s.StationId, v.DateAndTime, v.Val
order by s.StationId, v.DateAndTime desc
```

Comment: Going forward ,please provide test data like the one in the answer `Create table #values ([DateAndTime] datetime, [TPTagId] int, [Val] int)

insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:00:00.000', 7, 500)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:15:00.000', 7, 700)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:30:00.000', 7, 750)  
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:23:00.000', 8, 610)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:24:00.000', 8, 630)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:25:00.000', 8, 640)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using window functions:

```
Create table #values ([DateAndTime] datetime, [TPTagId] int, [Val] int)

insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:00:00.000', 7, 500)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:15:00.000', 7, 700)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:30:00.000', 7, 750)  
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:23:00.000', 8, 610)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:24:00.000', 8, 630)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:25:00.000', 8, 640)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:49:00.000', 9, 888)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:49:30.000', 9, 890)
insert into #values values ('2017-01-01 13:49:45.000', 9, 901)

;with Last_Dates as 
(
Select distinct TPTagId
    , First_Value([DateAndTime]) OVER (Partition by [TPTagId] order by [DateAndTime] Desc) as [DateAndTime]
    , First_Value([Val]) OVER (Partition by [TPTagId] order by [DateAndTime] Desc) as [Val]
from #values
),
Last_but_one_dates as
(
Select distinct v.TPTagId
    , First_Value(v.[Val]) OVER (Partition by v.[TPTagId] order by v.[DateAndTime] Desc) as [Val]
from #values v
left join Last_Dates ld on ld.TPTagId = v.TPTagId and ld.[DateAndTime] = v.[DateAndTime]
where ld.TPTagId is null
)
Select ld.[TPTagId] as StationID, abs(ld.[Val] - lb1.[Val]) as [Difference]
from Last_dates ld
inner join Last_but_one_dates lb1 on ld.[TPTagId] = lb1.[TPTagId]
```